# How to implement the same two browser instances all the time and put different links in each?

Tags: python, selenium, python-multiprocessing, threadpoolexecutor

I have this example of code:

```
import concurrent.futures    
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

links = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mechanitis_Polymnia_Chrysalis.jpg',
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:William_Cornwallis_as_Admiral_(cropped).jpg',
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Battle_of_Saint_Charles.jpg',
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Stephen_Curry_Shooting_(cropped)_(cropped).jpg']

def open(url):
    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)
    driver.get(url)
    print('+')

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as ex:
    for link in links:
        ex.submit(open, link)
```

Everything works well, and different links are pasted into each browser, which is what I want. **But each time, new browser windows are created**.

How to implement the same two browser instances all the time and put different links in each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code a little using the same driver instead of opening a new one and it's working

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

links = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mechanitis_Polymnia_Chrysalis.jpg',
         'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:William_Cornwallis_as_Admiral_(cropped).jpg',
         'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Battle_of_Saint_Charles.jpg',
         'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Stephen_Curry_Shooting_(cropped)_(cropped).jpg']


def open(url, index):
    drivers[index].execute_script(f"window.open('{url}','_self')")
    print('+')


NB_WINDOWS = 2
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
drivers = []
for i in range(NB_WINDOWS):
    drivers.append(webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions))

print("Drivers : ", len(drivers))

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as ex:
    i = 0
    for link in links:
        ex.submit(open, link, i % NB_WINDOWS)
        i = i+1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, yes, it works, but not exactly as I need. When run, the code opens one browser window and inserts all the links from the list into it at once, thereby creating as many tabs as there are links in the list. I need to open two browser windows and insert different links from the list into them, in turn, one replacing the other

Comment: I modify the code can you check ?